# Find unused function in vc2008?

Tags: c++, function

how to find unused functions in a c++ project vc2008

Comment: Hey slacker! Any progress with this? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always use "/OPT:REF" when creating release versions. This flag removes all unreferenced functions and will reduce the final binary substantially if there are many functions not being used (in our case we have a kernel with loads of methods used differently from different customized applications).

The "/VERBOSE" will send information about the linking session to the output window, or to stdout if you are linking on the command line. In the latter you can always redirect this to a file.

Using both flags together will make the output contain all eliminated functions and/or data that is never referenced.

Cheers!

Comment: yours works ..just now tried..I forgot to revisit this post after trying out 2 other answers below....Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Select "Run code Analysis on 'your project name'" from the Analyze/Build menu (according to your VS edition), VS will show a warning if there is an unused functions.

Comment: I dont find those options in my version of VS2008 (I dont have Team System)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use link.exe with [/map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7xkk3e2.aspx) and /mapinfo to generate a map file that tells you which functions aren't called.